# sufficient condition for varieties to meet transversally

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth variety and $Y, Z$ a subvarieties of $X$.

If $Y, Z$ are smooth and $dim(Y\cap Z)=dimY+dimZ-dimX$, then can I say that $Y$ and $Z$ **meet trasversally**?

Are some more conditions required?

Answer (score 1):

No: consider a case where $X = \mathbb{P}^2$, $Y$ is a smooth conic, and $Z$ is a line tangent to $Y$. In this case $Y \cap Z$ is the single point where $Z$ is tangent to $Y$, and the equality from your question obviously holds. However, line and conic do not meet transversally, since line is tangent to the conic.